# Authenticating azure mobile services with JS backend, using AAD and service-driven data-flow

Tags: authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to put together a workflow for running Azure database access via JS-backend mobile services and using Azure Active Directory (AAD) for authentication. Broadly, I've been following:

[Add Azure Active Directory Support to Azure Mobile Services-Enabled Windows Phone Apps](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2014/10/01/Add-Azure-Active-Directory-Support.aspx?Page=1)

for my development and structure, with a lot of reading of other tutorials, for instance:

[Register your apps to use an Azure Active Directory Account](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-register-active-directory-authentication/)

So far, I've gotten this to work using a .NET backend with client-directed authentication. The actual (streamlined) authentication code looks like:

```
AuthenticationResult token = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
        AADWebApplicationAppIdUri, AADClientApplicationClientId);

if (token != null && token.Status == AuthenticationStatus.Success) {
    Debug.WriteLine(token);
} else {
    token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AADWebApplicationAppIdUri,
        AADClientApplicationClientId, returnUri);
    Debug.WriteLine(token);
}
JObject payload = new JObject();
payload["access_token"] = token.AccessToken;
MobileServiceUser msres = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(
        MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, payload);
```

This works great, and the authentication goes through correctly. However, I really want to use the dynamic schema features that the JS backend comes with. (I did attempt to use migrations, but that proved to be a bigger headache than the authentication.) Unlike the .NET backend, the JS backend doesn't support client-directed authentication for AAD domains (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj710106.aspx), only service-directed authentication. Piecing together the code, it looks like it should be just:

```
MobileServiceUser msres = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(
        MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);
```

This runs, and the authentication gets the login information, then fails with the error:

> Additional technical information:
>
> Correlation ID: a9397d76-0c11-4936-ae1f-749aac8fed91
>
> Timestamp: 2015-02-22 03:45:14Z
>
> AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or  implied by any provided credentials and search for multi tenanted application  identifier has failed.

I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong with my setup or code. Let me know if you need more info to understand what's going on.

Comment: Just to clarify, this error occurs after the AAD login screen? Does the tenant of the user that triggered this error match the tenant in which the web application was registered?

Comment: Yes, after the login screen. I'm just using the default (onmicrosoft) tenants, so I think the answer to the second is yes.

Comment: Just to re-iterate Matthew's question.  Is the account you are using to sign in with in the SAME directory/tenant in which you registered the application?  Can you double check by looking at your configuration please?  The error message somewhat suggests otherwise...

Comment: I really appreciate the input, but I'm very unfamiliar with the Azure framework. I'll tell you what I can see... My user account byrel.mitchell shows up in my AAD, in the users tab. It's 'sourced from' my microsoft account (I'm pretty sure it has the same password as the microsoft account, so I assume this is simply using the microsoft account for the user account info.) I haven't defined a custom domain/tenant, so I'm still using azureprotectdir.onmicrosoft.com. I think this means my account is in the same tenant...

Comment: Also, when I do nothing but switch out the mobile service backend to .NET, and swap authentication code, the authentication goes through perfectly with the same user. So it sounds to me like it isn't a user account error.